# Converting VB.Net to C# -type or namespace not found

Tags: c#

I am converting a VB.Net project to C#. I declare some public structures in one module and access them in another. I get a "The type or namespace name 'ItemInfo' could not be found." - where ItemInfo is one of the structures. Here is code snippet where I declare the structure:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using dbAutoTrack.DataReports;
using dbAutoTrack.DataReports.PDFExport;

namespace PlanSchedule
{

    static class PlanScheduleBLL
    {

        #region "Structures"

        public struct ItemInfo
        {
            // LinearProcessTime = sum of bll level resource requirements; 
            // when more than one resource on a level, uses max time required;
            // not saved in database, used in order processing only
            public string ItemNumber;
            public string Description;
            public string MakeBuy;
            public long TotalShelfLife;
            public long ReceivedShelfLife;
            public float YieldPercentage;
            public float BatchSize;
            public float SafetyStock;
        }
```

...and this is where I reference it:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PlanSchedule
{
public partial class BuildToStockOrderEntry
{


    // slItemList
    // Key = <item number> - <item description> Value = item number
    private SortedList<string, string> slItemList = new SortedList<string, string>();
    // slItems
    // Key = item number Value = item info
    private SortedList<string, ItemInfo> slItems = new SortedList<string, ItemInfo>();
```

I do not know C# so I may have a problem in my syntax. Is my declaration of the SortedList using ItemInfo correct?

TIA,
John

Comment: Glad we could help. Please remember to accept an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You currently have the `ItemInfo` struct *nested* in the `static class PlanScheduleBLL`. You have two options:

- Pull it out of that class, and just into the namespace.
- If you *really* want it nested, you need to make `PlanScheduleBLL` public, and refer to it like `PlanScheduleBLL.ItemInfo`

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are declaring the struct inside another class.  You could reference it by doing:

```
private SortedList<string, PlanScheduleBLL.ItemInfo> slItems ...
```

But a much better approach would be to just define the struct outside of the class and directly in the namespace itself (i.e. get rid of the PlanScheduleBLL static class).

Answer (score 0):

Place the `ItemInfo` structure outside of the `PlanScheduleBLL` class.

Comment: Thank you Jonathon, Dylan and AVD! I moved the structures outside the class and it worked great. Seems that is a difference between VB.Net and C#. I have them within the class but seems the Public declaration allows VB.Net to access them from other modules.